# CPU stuck on minimum frequency after resume from suspend and unplugged (Dell Latitude E6540)

Tags: 13.10, dell, suspend, frequency

I have a Dell Latitude E6540 (4th gen. core i7 processor). When i resume from suspend, while on battery, the processor never scales frequecy up and stays at minimum frequency (800 MHz).

Does this problem affect anyone else? Is there a workaround (other than plugging the AC charger when resuming)?

I've submitted a bug report in launchpad (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1260112).

I'm on Ubuntu 13.10 64 bit.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Check this [wiki.archlinux.org page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/CPU_frequency_scaling#BIOS_frequency_limitation):

> Some CPU/BIOS configurations may have difficulties to scale to the
>   maximum frequency or scale to higher frequencies at all. This is most
>   likely caused by BIOS events telling the OS to limit the frequency
>   resulting in /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/bios_limit set to a
>   lower value.

Temporal solution:

```
# echo 1 > /sys/module/processor/parameters/ignore_ppc
```